# update screen automatically flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I have screen contains boxes as you see .after press on remove button the box25 was removed successfully from DB but  it still appear on screen .the box25 removed when i move to profile tab and back to box tab .

Remove function :

```
void removeBox(int id) async {
    // if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    String boxId = _boxNameController.text;

    boxApi.removeBox(id).then((data) {
      if (data != null) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
      /*  Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BoxSettings()));*/
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar1);
    }).catchError((error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.toString())));
    });
    setState(() {});
  }


  Future<String> removeBox(int id) async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    await checkInternet();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      'boxId': id,
    };
    print(body);
    inspect(body);
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.REMOVE_BOX),
        headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body));
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var data = body['message'];
      print(data);
      inspect(data);
      return data;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to remove box');
    }

  }
```

[image]

How i can remove box automatically from screen ?

Answer (score 0):

you did everything correctly... but when your response is successful then you should locally remove that box from the list and then you should call setState().

pseudoCode:-

```
/// Remove box ontap

onTap(){
/// server method call
.....
/// if response successful then remove box loacally
list.removeAt(index);
setState(){}

}
```

Comment: if (response.statusCode == 200) this condition will also work for you